# return value false from isDisplayed method

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
boolean text = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".sr_ctext>b")).isDisplayed();
System.out.println(text);
```

when ever `.sr_ctext>b` is not found, suite stops and when the element is found successfully then `true` is returned.

I want when the element is not found then it should return false in text variable not just stop the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you should get the WebElement in a first step and only check for isDisplayed if you get a result which is not null. Another solution would be to put your code in a try/catch block:

```java
boolean text;
try 
{
    text = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".sr_ctext>b")).isDisplayed();
}
catch (NoSuchElementException e)
{
    text = false;
}
System.out.println(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Code stops while trying to find the element which is not present. So it is better to see whether the element exists,

```
boolean isPresent = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".sr_ctext>b")).size() > 0;

if(isPresent==true){ 

   boolean text = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".sr_ctext>b")).isDisplayed();
   System.out.println(text);

}

else{
     text=isPresent; //false, in your case
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
         try 
         {
         text = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".sr_ctext>b")).isDisplayed();
         }
         catch (Exception NoSuchElementException)
         {
         }
```

Simply append try catch the handle exception.